# How to accomplish group join and multi table parameters in LINQ

Tags: linq-to-sql

I must have missed something in my LINQ training.  In Linq to SQL using c#, I want to query two tables, one with the foreign key to the other, and pass two parameters, one for each table.

IN SQL, it is something simple like

```
Select Value from Table1 T1 
INNER JOIN Table2 T2
On T1.DefID = T2.ID
Where T1.PollID = 1 
AND T2.Name = 'Question'
```

in LINQ, I get stuck!

```
var q = from t1 in dc.Table1
        join t2 in dc.Table2
        on t1.DefID equals t2.ID
        into newGroup
        where t1.PollID == 1   // here's where I get stuck!
        // how do I query t2?
        select newGroup;
```

Is my approach wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var q = from t1 in dc.Table1
    join t2 in dc.Table2
    on t1.DefID equals t2.ID
    where t1.PollID == 1 &&
    t2.Name == "Question"
    select new {
        Alias1 = t1.FieldName,
        Alias2 = t2.FieldName
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying comma instead of &&.